# How can I determine which mouse button raised the click event in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, mouseevent

I have a button that I trigger `OnClick` whenever there is a click on that button. I would like to know which Mouse button clicked on that button?

When I use the `Mouse.LeftButton` or `Mouse.RightButton`, both tell me "*realsed*" which is their states after the click.

I just want to know which one clicked on my button. If I change `EventArgs` to `MouseEventArgs`, I receive errors.

**XAML:** `<Button Name="myButton" Click="OnClick">`

```
private void OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//do certain thing. 
}
```

Comment: I found a better method then I originally suggested, and have edited my answer to include it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just using the Button's Click event, then the only mouse button that will fire it is the primary mouse button.

If you still need to know specifically whether it was the left or right button, then you can use the SystemInformation to obtain it.

```
void OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (SystemParameters.SwapButtons) // Or use SystemInformation.MouseButtonsSwapped
        {
            // It's the right button.
        }
        else
        {
            // It's the standard left button.
        }
    }
```

**Edit:** The WPF equivalent to SystemInformation is SystemParameters, which can be used instead. Though you can include System.Windows.Forms as a reference to obtain the SystemInformation without adversely effecting the application in any way.

Comment: thanks for  the hint.Though mine is not a System.Windows.Form.It's an XAML window (WPF).

Comment: ... yes, all my development is in XAML or Silverlight. This is for WPF, as you can clearly see by the RoutedEventArgs, System.Windows.Forms.Systeminformation is just the best and quickest way to get the Computer's system information in WPF.

Answer (score 6):

You can cast like below:

```
MouseEventArgs myArgs = (MouseEventArgs) e;
```

And then get the information with:

```
if (myArgs.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
{
    // do sth
}
```

The solution works in VS2013 and you do not have to use MouseClick event anymore ;)

Answer (score 0):

You're right, Jose, it's with MouseClick event. But you must add a little delegate:

this.button1.MouseDown += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.MyMouseDouwn);

And use this method in your form:

```
    private void MyMouseDouwn(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) 
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
           this.Text = "Right";

        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            this.Text = "Left";
    }
```

Comment: This is not correct for WPF, you'd need to use a MouseButtonEventArgs, and it doesn't have a button property, but instead every button's state.

Comment: but even with    
private void OnClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e), it gives me the same error of error of "No overload for 'OnClick' matches delegate 'System.Windows.RoutedEventHandler'

Comment: I deleted the OnClick delegate.

Answer (score 0):

OnClick is called after a mouse button is pressed and then released. At the time of the call, the key has already been released. It is necessary to remember the state when clicking and reset the state when processing OnClick, as well as after processing a double click.

Comment: More of a comment on an answer than a standalone answer of its own.